# PackageAdmin Closes Active Page

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

When I use the standard `PackageAdmin` to reload some bundles like that:

```
PackageAdmin packageAdmin = ServiceUtil.getService(PackageAdmin.class);
packageAdmin.refreshPackages(null);
```

the active page of the workbench (`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()`) gets visibly closed, and all calls to above method return null, rendering the application entirely useless - but as far as I can tell only if fragments were installed since the last call to `refreshPackages(...)`.

How can I prevent the page from getting closed or how can I reopen it?